# Error during updating dist files : Kernel Problem?

Tags: boot, package-management, upgrade, kernel

I have switched to Linux recently , so I'm a noob basically and apologies if I couldn't convey the proper information.

Past a month, I have install Ubuntu 20.04 as my only operating system and since I installed it, (The installation process weren't smooth however), I am encountering many issues ...

And I really enjoy fixing it though :)

But ,this issue I've faced has not asked in our community yet.. Please help me with it

```
krishnakumar@krish-Inspiron-5558:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core libseccomp2
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 186 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libseccomp2 amd64 2.4.3-1ubuntu3.20.04.2 [41.9 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 glib-networking-common all 2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1 [5,040 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 glib-networking amd64 2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1 [58.2 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 glib-networking-services amd64 2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1 [10.6 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools all 0.136ubuntu6.2 [9,200 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-core all 0.136ubuntu6.2 [47.5 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.136ubuntu6.2 [13.9 kB]
Fetched 186 kB in 1s (144 kB/s)             
(Reading database ... 196682 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libseccomp2_2.4.3-1ubuntu3.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libseccomp2:amd64 (2.4.3-1ubuntu3.20.04.2) over (2.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libseccomp2:amd64 (2.4.3-1ubuntu3.20.04.2) ...
(Reading database ... 196682 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-glib-networking-common_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking glib-networking-common (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) over (2.64.2-1build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-glib-networking_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking glib-networking:amd64 (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) over (2.64.2-1build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-glib-networking-services_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking glib-networking-services (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) over (2.64.2-1build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-initramfs-tools_0.136ubuntu6.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) over (0.136ubuntu6.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-initramfs-tools-core_0.136ubuntu6.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking initramfs-tools-core (0.136ubuntu6.2) over (0.136ubuntu6.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking initramfs-tools-bin (0.136ubuntu6.2) over (0.136ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up glib-networking-common (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools-bin (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
Setting up glib-networking-services (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up glib-networking:amd64 (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools-core (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
cp: error reading '/lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-piix4.ko': Input/output error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_iEqMdQ/lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-piix4.ko: Invalid argument
```

**Also importantly, I've facing busybox initfrms issues, which could be easily fixed by fsck command..** Hope I provided enough information.. Thank you in advance